# Is there a way to make my HTC-Incredible phone use the optical joystick button to wake up?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, screen, settings

I'm still adjusting from going from my iPod to an HTC Incredible phone.

One thing that is very non-intuitive for me is to press the power button when I want to "wake up the phone" after it has dimmed out. I'm just so used to using the big button on the bottom of my iPhone for this that I instinctively hit the "optical joystick" button all the time by accident.

Is there any way to configure the button so the optical joystick button can pull the phone out of sleep mode?

Answer (score 2):

This should actually be pretty easy and does not require rooting or custom ROMs, but you'll need a 'lockscreen replacement' app to do it.

The app 'WidgetLocker Lockscreen' allows 'Easy Wake' that allows you to customize which button (Home, menu, trackball, volume, etc) wakes the phone. Check it out on the market, it's $1.99.

There may also be other lockscreen replacement apps out there, but that is exactly what you need: a customizable lockscreen replacement app that supports the feature you requested. WidgetLocker is an example of this.

Answer (score 1):

CyanogenMod supports this on your phone, though you'll have to root and install it.

One thing I've noticed (and have seen others mention): It's not very reliable on the Droid Incredible.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  Sometimes you have to press the button multiple times to wake the phone, other times holding the button works, other times I've just have to give up and use the power button to wake the phone.  Other phones may be more or less reliable.

What does work well with CyanogenMod (and maybe other "lockscreen replacements") is using the button to unlock the phone.  Of course, if you're using a pin code, swipe pattern, or some other security measure to unlock, then that won't work so well.

Comment: Your reported unreliability may be phone-specific. My wife has had no issues using the "Menu" button on her Dream to wake the phone. (CM6)

Comment: @Broam: No doubt that different phones will have different behavior.  This question is specific to the HTC Incredible, but I'll update my answer to make that part clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not come across any app that lets you reassign the functions of the keys, it may be possible with a custom ROM image but I've not seen it mentioned.

Comment: CM supports this, see afraizer's answer.